# Where do I find .less files for Bootstrap 2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am looking for a Bootstrap 2 version of the Bootstrap less files. Here they are for the current version:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/less

Are the bootstrap 2 files gone, or can I find them in some other place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [these](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v2.3.2/less) files? You can pick an older version by selecting the right tag from the drop-down menu.